# What Windows API function can I use to emulate ControlClick & ControlSend from ahk?

Tags: c++, winapi

For an app I've been creating, I want to be able to create macros that are able to run without actually having to be tabbed in. Now `ControlClick` & `ControlSend` allow you to click or press key binds. I want to be able to do the same thing, but my app is in C++ using [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage).

I wasn't able to achieve this. Additionally, `ControlClick` from AHK works fine.

Here's the function I made for this:

```cpp
bool ControlClick(HWND hWnd, int x, int y) 
{
    try {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y)); 
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));  
        return true; 
    } catch (exception e) {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to control click message", e.what()); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or show me a function that can let me do this task?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (the same applies with `SendMessage()`). Use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead. In any case, [AHK is open-source](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey), so you can just look at what it actually does.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out using PostMessage was the answer.

Incase anyone else wants to do this 

        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));

Heres a example to click.